# Multiple belongsTo Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 models objects, namely: `Categories`, `Category_products` & `Products`

Categories:

```
<?php
class Categories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    public function product_ids() {
        return $this->hasMany("app\Models\categories\Category_products", "category_id", "id");
    }
?>
```

Category_products:

```
<?php
class Category_products extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'category_products';
    public function product_ids(){
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Models\categories\Category');
    }

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasOne("app\Models\Product", "id", "product_id");
    }
}
?>
```

And Product:

```
<?php
class Product extends Model  {
    protected $table = 'products';
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo("app\Models\categories\Category_products");
    }
?>
```

Now in my CategoryController I do:

```
 $this->data["products"] = Categories::find($id)->product_ids()->products()->get();
```

But now I get an error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::products()
```

How can I do this the right way ?

Comment: Your product_ids() return a belongsTo relationship to ''app\Models\categories\Category" that may be the cuase of your error.

Comment: How can it be causing the error, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I'm going to try.

I guess you missed something when reading the Laravel documentation.

You don't have to create the category_products Models because it's your pivot table between your Categories and your Product.

"Normally", you should have something like this :

Products :

```
. id
. name
```

Categories :

```
. id
. name
```

category_product (alphabetically ordered name)

```
. product_id
. category_id
```

And your Models:

```
class Category extends \Eloquent {

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('namespace\to\your\model\Product');
    }
}

class Product extends \Eloquent {

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('namespace\to\your\model\Category');
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following :

```
$this->data["products"] = Category::find($id)->products;
```

or

```
$this->data["products"] = Category::find($id)->products()->get();
```

Laravel will take care to call the pivot table for you.

It's not common to name your class with a plural, get used to name your class with their singular

And see also : http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: So, if I get it right, I don't have to tell anywhere to Laravel that category_products exists, it will detect it automatticaly?

Comment: If you follow the Laravel naming convention, no. But you can precise your table name in the second parameter of the belongsToMany method. Laravel retreive your pivot table with your class name (alphabetically ordered) if you don't pass any table name to belongsToMany